# convert RGB image to hexachrome/CIELAB/CIE XYZ

Tags: python, linux, colors, rgb, cmyk

I would like to use a python 2.7 script, that should work under Linux or Windows, to convert image from RGB to Hexachrome (or CIELAB or CIE XYZ). I wondered if there are any library that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with ImageMagick which runs as binaries at the command line in Windows, Linux, and OS X, or with Python, Perl, PHP, .NET bindings. Check it out at [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org).

In your case, CIELab is identical to ImageMagick's `Lab` colorspace, so you can do

```
convert input.jpg -colorspace lab output.tif
```

for example. If your input image is just binary data, your can also read that in ImageMagick, but you will need to specify the size and endianness in advance of reading it in, something along these lines:

```
convert -size 512x512 -depth 16 -endian MSB image.rgb -colorspace lab output.tif
```

You can convert to other file formats too - so long as they support Lab colourspace.